# how to calculate a total power consumption of LED

Tags: led

how can I calculate a total power consumption by given % of photons exit each LED and the Internal quantum efficiency and the Total light intensity? what kind of formula I should use?

Comment: I x V. That's all there is to it.

Comment: you probably want to visit the physics department for that question. http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks Trevor for your prompt help.  I've figured it out.  Since I don't have I nor V I can't use equation P=IV.  Therefore, I used the ratio of total light intensity and the internal quantum efficiency x % of photon exit each LED.  I got the answer.

Comment: Data sheet for the LED, please.

Comment: Hi Brian et al.,

Comment: Hi Brian et al., here is the problem:                               Assuming that the internal quantum efficiency [1] of each LED in the traffic signal shown in problem 5 is 90%, what is the total power consumption of each LED in the traffic signal?

[1] The internal quantum efficiency of an LED is defined as the proportion of injected electron-hole pairs in the photon which recombine and emit a photon.  Note not all of these photons will escape the device – many will be totally internally reflected.

Comment: note: from the previous problem, for every photon created inside the semiconductor of the LED, 22.9 percent of them exit the device

Answer (score 1):

The total electrical power consumption is the forward voltage x current.

The total power is divided between heat and light generation.

The Internal quantum efficiency comes into play when looking at the number of photons absorbed within the LED and the number of photons exiting the LED each second.

If you know the efficacy of the LED materials in generating the photons and you know the quantum efficiency of the LED and the phosphors then yes you can calculate the power by counting the number of photons exiting the LED.

Since you are counting the photons per second the formula should be in Quantum Photonic terms.  The measurement would be Photon Flux (in moles per second) divided by the quantum efficiency divided by the LED efficacy.

BTW, Intensity is not the same as flux.  Flux is the radiant energy (quantity and speed) of the photons where Intensity is the density of the photons.  Radiometric and Quantium Photonic Intensity are the measured amount of power radiated per unit solid angle, measured in Watts/steradian and Luminous Intensity candela (lm/steradian).

Flux is the power (energy per unit time t) emitted, transferred, or received in the form of electromagnetic radiation (photons) measured in Watts (Radiometric), Lumens (Photometric), or moles/second (Quantum Photonic).

[image]

---

**You can see the varying Intensity as the exit angle changes.**

[image]

Comment: Perfect explanation indeed!   Thanks Misunderstood!  This is GREAT!